# Powershell FileSystemWatcher - Avoiding duplicate action on Create

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

It's a known issue in Powershell that the FileSystemWatcher fires twice on events. I am trying to work around this as I am watching for files being created and then pushing it to a printer. The double firing means I am getting duplicated printouts

I know this question has been asked before but I am a complete newb when it comes to Powershell (and scripting in general really) so some of the answers have gone straight over my head

In the code, I am watching a folder and then passing the subdirectory names as the printer name for sending the job. This is because the software in use is copying the pdf files from a remote location into those folders (the software doesn't have direct access to the printers due to citrix)

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "L:\Label\"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $printer = Split-Path (Split-Path $path -Parent) -Leaf
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path, $printer"
                Add-content "c:\prog\log.txt" -value $logline
                C:\prog\SumatraPDF.exe -print-to "\\http://srv:631\$printer" $path
              }    

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I expect to see the printing command (the Sumatra call) only occur once when a pdf file is dropped into the watch folder

Comment: You are absolutely correct about filesystemwatcher events firing multiple times. Not sure why the responder thinks his knowledge is so comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of telling you what you should or shouldn't do, here is how to do what you asked for:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$global:canDoEvent = $True #NEW
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "L:\Label\"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
```

#### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED

```
$action = { if ($global:canDoEvent) { #NEW
                $global:canDoEvent = $False #NEW
                $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $printer = Split-Path (Split-Path $path -Parent) -Leaf
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path, $printer"
                Add-content "c:\prog\log.txt" -value $logline
                C:\prog\SumatraPDF.exe -print-to "\\http://srv:631\$printer" $path
            }
          }
```

#### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED

```
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -EventName newFile -Action $action #NEW
do { #NEW
     $global:canDoEvent = $True
     Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier newFile -Timeout 1
   } while ($True)
```

It probably requires tuning, I'm no expert, but that's the idea.

Basically, add a global boolean var = True, put your wait-event on a timeout inside a do-while loop, make variable true every loop, then in your event action, make it false. your timeout will define how often the event can fire. a single second should suffice to prevent multiple firing events. Obviously, if there are contexts where more than 1 unique file could be created and printed during the same second, it would skip them.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a known issue that the FileSystemWatcher fires twice on events, not where you got that information.

Regardless, if I were you I wouldn't code the FileSystemWather events in Powershell myself, it's a real pain.

Instead, you can use Powershell Guard, just pass the print command instead of the TestCommand. https://github.com/smurawski/PowerShellGuard

All that PowerGuard does is abstract the use of the FileSystemWatcher. You can create your print command in a Powershell script, and just have PowerGuard call your script with -TestCommand "Print.ps1 .\PathToYourFile"

**Final Solution (by the poster himself):**

```
dir \\srv\label\prnlblCuts\*.pdf | New-Guard -TestCommand "C:\PROG\SumatraPDF.exe -print-to \\srv-tsv:631\prnlblCuts" -TestPath "$($_.FullName)" -Wait
```

Comment: I only say "known issue" because a quick google finds lots of people complaining about the multiple firing of events. I'm sure it's by design, but just a real pain to handle :)

Comment: I'm having a play with PowershellGuard now. My confusion though is whether I can still pass variables like I was doing in my original Powershell script?

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I think the problem is widely misrepresented. A lot of people struggle with the FileSystemWatcher and it understanding the event it fires. Let me know if you need an example of using the PowerGuard module.

Comment: Ah! Ok I'll give that a try :)

Comment: I can't see to see a mapped network drive with Guard. If I do -Path c:\ -PathFilter "*.pdf", the script is triggered

However I need to watch l:\ (a mapped network drive). Doesn't seem to let me do it though

Comment: Yeah, that gets a bit complicated. Your network drive has to be mapped in Powershell with New-PSDrive and be persisted.

Comment: I've found a way around it by using the full path. I'm just trying to work through some kinks now regarding how to pass the printer and file name. I think I might be able to avoid using a second script altogether

Comment: You don't know how to pass the file name of the found file by any chance? This is the last bit I'm stuck on. It's not pretty, but I can see it's at least calling Sumatra but fails because I don't know what the file to print actually is :)

Comment: New-Guard -Path \\srv\label\prnlblCuts -PathFilter '*.pdf' -TestCommand "C:\PROG\SumatraPDF.exe -print-to \\http://srv-tsv:631\prnlblCuts \\srv\label\prnlblCuts\FILENAME"
Wait-Guard

Comment: Doh! Let me check PowerGuard. Not aware of how to pass the filename yet.

Comment: Still not alot of luck :( Can I remove the file after processing? It seems like it's trying to pick up every file in the folder each time it runs

Comment: The interesting thing is that I can get it to print (to screen) a file... but it also tries to print the folder name itself to pdf (and obvious fails). This is even with a filter for pdf files only

Comment: Yes... oddly enough I used a similar script from another source, made my changes and it only triggers once now. It's strange because I can't really see any real functional difference between the two that could explain the difference in behaviour

Comment: This may be a workaround, but it is not a solution to the problem of events firing multiple times, which happens a lot in the powershell universe and needs some solutions...